# Ajax Image Gallery Uploader

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I was just wondering what is the best image uploader with a gallery and ordering abilities. What I had in mind was a back-end page that has thumbnail images to the left, and an image upload panel to the right. When an image gets uploaded, the thumbnails in the left gets updated. I also need a delete function on all of the thumbnails; maybe when they hover over an image, an "x" could appear, which when clicked, will delete the image. I'll also need dragging capabilities so that the user can rearrange the ordering of the images.

I was hoping for all this to be using javascript and ajax. I think it should be possible because I can find each piece from separate plugins, but I want one that encapsulates all of them together.

Comment: You're right, it can be done with jQuery, but I was hoping for a prebuilt solution instead of starting from scratch. I know that I could probably take an existing plugin and modify it, but that would be a lot of overhead time-wise vs a drop-in solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use Uploadify from http://www.uploadify.com/demos/
and customize it as u need.

there is no prebuilt solution for your case.